# plt.imshow() gives TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float using PyTorch

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, pytorch

I am trying to create a custom Dataset Processor for a set of images. However, when I try to view the images in my dataset, I get hit with the TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float.

I tried to check if I am passing in a PIL Image into the plt.imshow() function and I am.

```
class DatasetProcessing(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, input_data, output_data, transform=None): 
        self.transform = transform
        self.input_data = 
        input_data.reshape((-1,64,64)).astype(np.float32)[:,:,:,None]
        self.output_data = output_data 

    def __getitem__(self, index): 
        return self.transform(self.input_data[index]), self.output_data[index]

    def __len__(self): 
        return len(list(self.input_data))

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage()])


dset_train = DatasetProcessing(X_slices_train, Y_train, transform)


train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dset_train, batch_size=4, 
                                      shuffle=True, num_workers=4) 

plt.figure(figsize = (16, 4))
for num, x in enumerate(dset_train):
    plt.subplot(1,6,num+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    print(x)
    plt.imshow(np.asarray(x))
    plt.title(y_train[num])
```

I expected to get pictures of my dataset, but instead I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-8b8caac49d97> in <module>
      4     plt.axis('off')
      5     print(x)
----> 6     plt.imshow(np.asarray(x))
      7     plt.title(y_train[num])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, data, **kwargs)
   2675         filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad, imlim=imlim,
   2676         resample=resample, url=url, **({"data": data} if data is not
-> 2677         None else {}), **kwargs)
   2678     sci(__ret)
   2679     return __ret

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1587     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1588         if data is None:
-> 1589             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1590 
   1591         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    367                 f"%(removal)s.  If any parameter follows {name!r}, they "
    368                 f"should be pass as keyword, not positionally.")
--> 369         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    370 
    371     return wrapper

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/deprecation.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    367                 f"%(removal)s.  If any parameter follows {name!r}, they "
    368                 f"should be pass as keyword, not positionally.")
--> 369         return func(*args, **kwargs)
    370 
    371     return wrapper

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, shape, filternorm, filterrad, imlim, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5658                               resample=resample, **kwargs)
   5659 
-> 5660         im.set_data(X)
   5661         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5662         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
    676                 not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, float, "same_kind")):
    677             raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
--> 678                             "float".format(self._A.dtype))
    679 
    680         if not (self._A.ndim == 2

TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Using tags wisely will help you getting your question answered faster; this is a `python` `matplotlib` issue, and it has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` (tags edited).

Answer (score 1):

Your `dset_train` yields `self.transform(self.input_data[index]), self.output_data[index]` if understood correctly `self.transform(self.input_data[index])` is an image tensor (data) and `self.output_data[index]` is a label, but here:

```py
plt.imshow(np.asarray(x))
```

you are passing unpacked `x` which is actually (data, label)

So, you need to unpack it first:

```py
plt.figure(figsize = (16, 4))
for num, x in enumerate(dset_train):
    data, label = x
    plt.subplot(1,6,num+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    print(x)
    plt.imshow(np.asarray(data))
    plt.title(y_train[num])
```

**EDIT:**

> Why I have to unpack x?

You're inheriting from PyTorch's `Dataset`, and according to [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset):

> All datasets that represent a map from keys to data samples should subclass it. All subclasses should overrite `__getitem__()`, supporting fetching a data sample for a given key.

In your defined `DatasetProcessing` class `__getitem__()` returns a tuple of 2 items: `self.transform(self.input_data[index])` and `self.output_data[index]`, the first one is data, the second one is appropriate label. And that's why you need to unpack it like `data, y = x`, because your `DatasetProcessing` dataset yields data and a label.

> Is there any documentation/tutorials you can link me to?

I can recommend you this links:

- [Data Loading and Processing Tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html)
- [Dataset docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset)
- [`torch.utils.data` docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html)

Comment: Thank you! That worked, I am not particularly understanding why I have to unpack x. I am new to PyTorch; is there any documentation/tutorials you can link me to?